# How to Build flutter Apk in mobile?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Excuse me guys, I'm sorry. I want to ask, can I install flutter on my Android Mobile ?? I tried to search on Google but the results failed, from trying to install on Termux but failed, try to install on VHEditor but the problem is I can't install flutter SDK in Environment Variable. maybe you guys can answer my question.so, can i build flutter apk in android mobile??

Comment: sorry guys, I mean, how do I build a Flutter application on an Android mobile ??so build the apk on android mobile,not on a computer

Comment: Not turn-key/easy based on this [Termux issue: Building Flutter crashes Termux](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/1247) due to Flutter's dependencies although there is appears to be some progress in this Flutter issue ticket: [Add support for Linux host ARM](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56992)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you meant building an apk version of the app instead of running it on an emulator.

To do that run in your IDE terminal or flutter console

```
Flutter build apk
```

Comment: Sorry guys,i mean,can we build flutter project in termux or android platform without computer or laptop??

Comment: yes you can https://www.hax4us.com/2021/12/install-flutter-in-termux.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no way of installing Flutter on phone, The best way to use flutter on phone is to ssh into a server and compile it's apk

Answer (score 0):

yes we can build flutter apps in mobile through termux and here is simple guide for reference but i am still giving simple one liner installing command but for "how to use" please check reference link

`curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Hax4us/flutter_in_termux/master/install.sh | bash -s`

reference : https://www.hax4us.com/2021/12/install-flutter-in-termux.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

answer is , Yes. you can install flutter in termux.
you can use linux_arm64 interpreter for Flutter SDK binary.

###### Install Flutter in termux

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bdloser404/Fluttermux/main/install.sh)"
```

> This is Termux Native support. That means there is no Proot or Chroot setup. You will get full Flutter Development Environment experience.

Reference Link & Docs: https://github.com/bdloser404/Fluttermux (opensource)